# How can I set the publish_down and publish_up fields in a own Joomla 3 component?

Tags: web, joomla, calendar, publish, custom-component

How can I set the publish_down and publish_up fields in a own Joomla 3 component? 
My component has a view "company". This view has controller, table in database("companies") and model.

The table has created_date(calendar field), publish_up(calendar field), publish_down(calendar field), state fields. And I made a form for the company view where I can set the dates. The created date default value is "NOW" in the form. So It's working. And I can set in the status too (published/unpublished).

But how can I set the auto publish on a date and auto unpublish on the publis up and publish down fields? I don't find information about this... :/ How does it work this in the content component? Where can I find this functions in joomla?

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where my component had both `publish_up` and `publish_down` columns on the item, but I had to update the `getListQuery()` in my model and add the following:

```
// Define null and now dates
$nullDate = $db->quote($db->getNullDate());
$nowDate = $db->quote(JFactory::getDate()->toSql());

// Filter by start and end dates.
if ((!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_phambili')) && (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit', 'com_phambili'))) {
    $query->where('(a.publish_up = ' . $nullDate . ' OR a.publish_up <= ' . $nowDate . ')')
        ->where('(a.publish_down = ' . $nullDate . ' OR a.publish_down >= ' . $nowDate . ')');
}
```